# tbl_summary() not showing YES/NO levels in R

Tags: r, dplyr, categorical-data, gtsummary

in data frame below g variable has two levels, however tbl_summary() is not showing the its levels.

```
data.frame(a=c(0,1,2),
           
           b=c(0,1,2),
           
           f=c("m", "f", "m"),
           
           g = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"),
           
           output = c(0,1,0)) %>%
  
  tbl_summary(by=output)

  a b f   g output
1 0 0 m Yes      0
2 1 1 f  No      1
3 2 2 m Yes      0
```

[image]

I tried following [R gtsummary package doesnt show the factor levels in the summary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485245/r-gtsummary-package-doesnt-show-the-factor-levels-in-the-summary-table) but unfortunately I could not solve this issue. I would appreciate any hint or help with this?

Comment: It's not an issue, it's a feature - `g` is a dichotomous variable; `tbl_summary` notices that and correctly shows frequency and proportion of the "Yes" - showing the "No" values is pointless because it can be derived by subtracting the total from the Yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R gtsummary package doesnt show the factor levels in the summary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485245/r-gtsummary-package-doesnt-show-the-factor-levels-in-the-summary-table)

Comment: Yes, rationally. but I believe visually it is more interesting and readable to have them shown as well. so is there any way to force gtsummary show both levels. specially since it is not obvious that if 2 represents yes or no. it does not even show the levels are yes or no.

Comment: @harre, unfortunately not, as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Mathica As shown in my answer below it does show the levels using your data, so it's not clear what the problem is. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `type` in `tbl_summary` to specify how to display it.

**For specific columns:**

```r
library(gtsummary)

df |> tbl_summary(by = output, type = list(g ~ "categorical"))
```

**All "Yes"/"No" columns:**

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(stringr)

names_of_yes_no_columns <- names(Filter(function(x) all(str_detect(x, "Yes|No")), df))

df |> tbl_summary(by = output, type = list(names_of_yes_no_columns ~ "categorical"))
```

**All dichotomous variables (@Daniel D. Sjoberg):**

```r
library(gtsummary)

df |> tbl_summary(by = output, type = all_dichotomous() ~ "categorical")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. however the problem with this approach is it does not come useful when there are many number columns with YES/NO or 1/0 levels.

Comment: But this is the way. You could update your question with this addition, and someone (or me) could help you automate that. Alternatively recode "No" to "N" and "Yes" to "Y".

Comment: If you want all dichotomous variables to be shown as categories, use `type = all_dichotomous() ~ "categorical"`